# Separate months inside SQL output

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, name, date FROM money_month WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}';
```

It returns me rows like that:

```
| id | name   | date       |
|----|--------|------------|
| 1  | Mike   | 2018-09-05 |
| 2  | Nelson | 2018-09-07 |
| 3  | Bity   | 2018-09-08 |
| 4  | Ory    | 2018-10-04 |
```

If I use Group by like:

```
SELECT id, name, date FROM money_month WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}' GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY date DESC;
```

it works, but shows only first row from each month, like this:

```
| id        | name | date       |
|-----------|------|------------|
| September |      |            |
| 1         | Mike | 2018-09-05 |
| October   |      |            |
| 4         | Ory  | 2018-10-04 |
```

Is possible to separate rows with months, to look like this?

```
| id        | name   | date       |
|-----------|--------|------------|
| September |        |            |
| 1         | Mike   | 2018-09-05 |
| 2         | Nelson | 2018-09-07 |
| 3         | Bity   | 2018-09-08 |
| October   |        |            |
| 4         | Ory    | 2018-10-04 |
```

My SQL output

```
$month = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        if($month != $row["date"])
        {
            $month = substr($row["date"],5,2);
            if ($month == "10") { $output= "October"; }
            if ($month == "9") { $output= "September"; }

            echo $output;
        }
```

**Trying to achieve someting like this:** [image]

But my output looks like this: [image]

Comment: `order by date`

Comment: @splash58 Already tried that, and it still outputs only one row for each month (with group). Without GROUP BY, ORDER BY doesn't generate rows with months.

Comment: @splash58 When using ORDER BY MONTH(date), name of the month is printed to each row and not only one row above whole month.

Comment: Could you add full query with group by, which you tired ?

Comment: @Eugene GROUP BY querry added.

Comment: "rowspan" is best done in the app as it generates the output.  It is too clumsy (in my opinion) to do the task in SQL.  In html tables, use `rowspan` in the `td` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of PHP code that should make a good start to what you want to achieve. It is based on your sample `money_month` table and your desired output image.

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, date FROM money_month ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die("Query failed!");
$month = $year = 0;
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $row['date']);
    $this_year = (int)$date->format('Y');
    $this_month = (int)$date->format('n');
    if ($year != $this_year) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan = \"3\">$this_year</td></tr>\n";
        $year = $this_year;
    }
    if ($month != $this_month) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $date->format('M') . "</td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['date']}</td>";
        $month = $this_month;
    }
    else {
        echo "<tr><td></td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['date']}</td>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

This will give you an output that looks something like this, which you should then be able to style as you need:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td colspan = "3">2018</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Oct</td><td>Ory</td><td>2018-10-04</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sep</td><td>Bity</td><td>2018-09-08</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>Nelson</td><td>2018-09-07</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>Mike</td><td>2018-09-05</td></tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: This is exacly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly the question, you just need order by date

```
SELECT YEAR(date) desc, MONTH(date),  id, name, date 
FROM money_month 
WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}' 
Order BY 1 desc,   2 desc
```

When you use Group by, you should [aggregate](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx) columns, which are not in group by clause

Comment: Add the query, please. It's really hard to understand the problem without seeing full picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sql:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) y, MONTH(date) m, name, date FROM ta WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}' ORDER BY y desc, m desc, date desc;
```

And, query result like this:

```
y       m   id  name    date
2018    9   4   klkvv   2018-09-18
2018    9   1   fsdfsa  2018-09-01
2018    7   3   mujfis  2018-07-05
```

Then you can use `y` and `m` to match year and month.

Comment: This is still not what i'm asking here. I'm trying just to group months, like is displayed on the first picture above.

Comment: I found the reason why your output is not same with what you exceped, you used `$month = substr($row["date"],5,2);` statement to cover the `$month`, but `$row["date"]` in `$month != $row["date"]` is always like `2018-09-01`, so this statement is not useful. So, in your php code, you add another variable to determine the month is same with last month, if it is, set `$output = ''`